# XAML/C#/Webbrowser Run C# code after JS onload()

Tags: c#, xaml, events, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF XAML form backed with C#.
Embedded on the XAML form is a `WebBrowser` control.
The control loads an html page and displays it.

I have an JS `onload` method on the HTML page.
I have some C# code that I'd like to run based on the content of the page, but I'd like to do it after the DOM is loaded AND the `onload` JS code has completed.

I added a `LoadCompleted` method to the `WebBrowser` but it gets called before the `onload` JS code has been run.

Is there a different event that I can try to capture that will trigger the C# code to run only after the `onload` JS has completed?

**Edit -- Workaround**

My workaround now is to call the JS `onload` method from C# in the `LoadCompleted`  method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
 string loaded = await  Webbrowser.InvokeScriptAsync("Loaded", new string[] { /*Here your JS loaded method which should echo for example loaded*/});
```

Then after the script was invoked and returned for example "loaded" you can go on.